# Javascript Does not Recognize SWT BrowserFunction

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am trying to embed html&javascript file to an Eclipse plug-in using SWT Browser.

I want to call a function declared in Java in Javascript I loaded using BrowserFunction, but it seems Javascript does not recognize this function I declared.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);
    new ReadFileFunction(browser, "test");

    browser.setUrl("file:///C:/Users/asder/Desktop/timeline/index.html");

}

class ReadFileFunction extends BrowserFunction {

    public ReadFileFunction(Browser browser, String name) {
        super(browser, name);
    }

    @Override
    public Object function(Object[] arguments) {
        System.out.println("asdasdsdad");
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

For the Javascript, I have:

```
<script>    
    try {
        var result = test();
        alert(result);
    } catch(e) {
        alert('a java error occurred: ' + e.message);
    }
</script>
```

It is simply alerting saying it doesn't have a function called 'test'.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Eclipse?  What platform?  What browser?  There have been several issues with `BrowserFunction`, like https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=269198 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=269285 ...

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure the function sticks around by making sure it isn't garbage collected.
Something like:

    `final BrowserFunction rff = new ReadFileFunction(browser, "test");`

That's what I do for my browser functions...